# Retrieve the price for Product from stripe using laravel Cashier

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Suppose i have created a product on stripe with **API ID "price_1IYwYtA4vM4p6MlHCuiAZx9X" of cost $25.00USD**

So how can we retrieve the cost of this product using API id using laravel cashier?

Answer (score 4):

As @Nolan H has explained already thoose are two different Entities and you have to make two api calls to merge the items together.

So having this in mind you can do this with a little trick on your own.
Below you can find my solution how I did it. I have **products** with different payment interval and **prices**.
In the frontend later I display the tiers to the user and can continue the payment process with the price_id.

### The Solution

```php
    public function products(){
        $stripe = Cashier::stripe();
        $products = $stripe->products->all(); // here you get all products
        $prices   = $stripe->prices->all();   // here you get all prices

        $items = []; // init empty array 
        $pkgs = (new PackageController)->getPackages(); // I have my own conditions saved here in my Controller ( see below ) 

        // Loop though each product and create your own schema
        foreach($products->data as $product):
          $key = $product->id;
          $tier = strtolower($product->name);
          $items[$key] = [];
          $items[$key]['id']   = $product->id;
          $items[$key]['tier'] = $tier;
          $items[$key]['name'] = $product->name;
          $items[$key]['metakey'] = $product->metadata;

          // I have only month and year prices, so I prefill them here
          $items[$key]['month'] = ['id' => null, 'price' => null];
          $items[$key]['year']  = ['id' => null, 'price' => null];

          // here I am binding my conditions from my package to the product (nothing to do with stripe, but my app, like having limits on stuff x)
          if(array_key_exists($tier, $pkgs))
            $items[$key]['condition'] = $pkgs[$tier];
          else
            $items[$key]['condition'] = [];

        endforeach;

        // now we need to add the existing prices for the products
        foreach($prices->data as $price):
          if($price->active == false) continue; // skip all archived prices 

          $key = $price->product;
          $items[$key][$price->recurring->interval]['id'] = $price->id;
          $items[$key][$price->recurring->interval]['price'] = $price->unit_amount;
        endforeach;


        return response()->json([
            'items' => $items,          // I work with my products <> price bindings here
            'products'  => $products,   // stripe response for products
            'prices'    => $prices,     // stripe response for prices
        ]);
    }
```

### The full response

The interesting part here is the **items** key with our own schema.
You can change the keys to be the product name instead of the prod_id.

```json
{
    "items": {
        "prod_L7Ay2QFGIFGWd7": {
            "id": "prod_L7Ay2QFGIFGWd7",
            "tier": "business",
            "name": "Business",
            "metakey": [],
            "month": {
                "id": "price_1KQwc6Ha5WPIKK5IM2tdjzCY",
                "price": 2490
            },
            "year": {
                "id": "price_1KQwc6Ha5WPIKK5I27jjkNd8",
                "price": 24900
            },
            "condition": {
                "users": "unlimited",
                "objects": "unlimited",
                "customer_management": true,
                "object_management": true,
                "employee_management": true,
                "task_management": true,
                "chat": true,
                "check_in": true,
                "storage": "individual",
                "task_extension": true,
                "multilanguage": true,
                "support_default": true,
                "support_extended": true,
                "emergency": true,
                "formular_documents": true,
                "time_tracking": true,
                "calendar": true,
                "location_tracking": true,
                "warehouse_management": true
            }
        },
        "prod_L7AxRKWZcChK9F": {
            "id": "prod_L7AxRKWZcChK9F",
            "tier": "premium",
            "name": "Premium",
            "metakey": [],
            "month": {
                "id": "price_1KnjlbHa5WPIKK5IjVleb0hR",
                "price": 2490
            },
            "year": {
                "id": "price_1KnjlzHa5WPIKK5InPCHJHZ1",
                "price": 26880
            },
            "condition": {
                "users": 15,
                "objects": "unlimited",
                "customer_management": true,
                "object_management": true,
                "employee_management": true,
                "task_management": true,
                "chat": true,
                "check_in": true,
                "storage": "15 GB",
                "task_extension": true,
                "multilanguage": true,
                "support_default": true,
                "support_extended": true,
                "emergency": true,
                "formular_documents": true,
                "time_tracking": true,
                "calendar": "optional",
                "location_tracking": "optional",
                "warehouse_management": "optional"
            }
        },
        "prod_L6ugqTDvGjaptE": {
            "id": "prod_L6ugqTDvGjaptE",
            "tier": "startup",
            "name": "StartUp",
            "metakey": {
                "popular": "true"
            },
            "month": {
                "id": "price_1KnjZAHa5WPIKK5I1MgPKICU",
                "price": 1749
            },
            "year": {
                "id": "price_1KnjZsHa5WPIKK5IKzYgCusH",
                "price": 18900
            },
            "condition": {
                "users": 5,
                "objects": 10,
                "customer_management": true,
                "object_management": true,
                "employee_management": true,
                "task_management": true,
                "chat": true,
                "check_in": true,
                "storage": "5 GB",
                "task_extension": true,
                "multilanguage": true,
                "support_default": true,
                "support_extended": true,
                "emergency": true,
                "formular_documents": "optional",
                "time_tracking": "optional",
                "calendar": "optional",
                "location_tracking": "optional",
                "warehouse_management": "optional"
            }
        },
        "prod_L6odxlRhol6BLN": {
            "id": "prod_L6odxlRhol6BLN",
            "tier": "basic",
            "name": "Basic",
            "metakey": [],
            "month": {
                "id": "price_1KnkAGHa5WPIKK5IhewMTNFP",
                "price": 0
            },
            "year": {
                "id": "price_1KnkAPHa5WPIKK5IWvZgqD66",
                "price": 0
            },
            "condition": {
                "users": 1,
                "objects": 1,
                "customer_management": true,
                "object_management": true,
                "employee_management": true,
                "task_management": true,
                "chat": true,
                "check_in": true,
                "storage": "100 MB",
                "task_extension": true,
                "multilanguage": true,
                "support_default": false,
                "support_extended": false,
                "emergency": false,
                "formular_documents": false,
                "time_tracking": false,
                "calendar": false,
                "location_tracking": false,
                "warehouse_management": false
            }
        }
    },
    "products": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "prod_L7Ay2QFGIFGWd7",
                "object": "product",
                "active": true,
                "attributes": [],
                "created": 1644337942,
                "description": null,
                "images": [],
                "livemode": false,
                "metadata": [],
                "name": "Business",
                "package_dimensions": null,
                "shippable": null,
                "statement_descriptor": null,
                "tax_code": "txcd_10103000",
                "type": "service",
                "unit_label": null,
                "updated": 1644337942,
                "url": null
            },
            {
                "id": "prod_L7AxRKWZcChK9F",
                "object": "product",
                "active": true,
                "attributes": [],
                "created": 1644337883,
                "description": null,
                "images": [],
                "livemode": false,
                "metadata": [],
                "name": "Premium",
                "package_dimensions": null,
                "shippable": null,
                "statement_descriptor": null,
                "tax_code": "txcd_10103000",
                "type": "service",
                "unit_label": null,
                "updated": 1649770127,
                "url": null
            },
            {
                "id": "prod_L6ugqTDvGjaptE",
                "object": "product",
                "active": true,
                "attributes": [],
                "created": 1644277375,
                "description": null,
                "images": [],
                "livemode": false,
                "metadata": {
                    "popular": "true"
                },
                "name": "StartUp",
                "package_dimensions": null,
                "shippable": null,
                "statement_descriptor": null,
                "tax_code": "txcd_10103000",
                "type": "service",
                "unit_label": null,
                "updated": 1649769377,
                "url": null
            },
            {
                "id": "prod_L6odxlRhol6BLN",
                "object": "product",
                "active": true,
                "attributes": [],
                "created": 1644254861,
                "description": null,
                "images": [],
                "livemode": false,
                "metadata": [],
                "name": "Basic",
                "package_dimensions": null,
                "shippable": null,
                "statement_descriptor": null,
                "tax_code": null,
                "type": "service",
                "unit_label": null,
                "updated": 1649771641,
                "url": null
            }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "url": "/v1/products"
    },
    "prices": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "price_1KnkAPHa5WPIKK5IWvZgqD66",
                "object": "price",
                "active": true,
                "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                "created": 1649771641,
                "currency": "eur",
                "livemode": false,
                "lookup_key": null,
                "metadata": [],
                "nickname": null,
                "product": "prod_L6odxlRhol6BLN",
                "recurring": {
                    "aggregate_usage": null,
                    "interval": "year",
                    "interval_count": 1,
                    "trial_period_days": null,
                    "usage_type": "licensed"
                },
                "tax_behavior": "inclusive",
                "tiers_mode": null,
                "transform_quantity": null,
                "type": "recurring",
                "unit_amount": 0,
                "unit_amount_decimal": "0"
            },
            {
                "id": "price_1KnkAGHa5WPIKK5IhewMTNFP",
                "object": "price",
                "active": true,
                "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                "created": 1649771632,
                "currency": "eur",
                "livemode": false,
                "lookup_key": null,
                "metadata": [],
                "nickname": null,
                "product": "prod_L6odxlRhol6BLN",
                "recurring": {
                    "aggregate_usage": null,
                    "interval": "month",
                    "interval_count": 1,
                    "trial_period_days": null,
                    "usage_type": "licensed"
                },
                "tax_behavior": "inclusive",
                "tiers_mode": null,
                "transform_quantity": null,
                "type": "recurring",
                "unit_amount": 0,
                "unit_amount_decimal": "0"
            },
            {
                "id": "price_1KnjlzHa5WPIKK5InPCHJHZ1",
                "object": "price",
                "active": true,
                "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                "created": 1649770127,
                "currency": "eur",
                "livemode": false,
                "lookup_key": null,
                "metadata": [],
                "nickname": null,
                "product": "prod_L7AxRKWZcChK9F",
                "recurring": {
                    "aggregate_usage": null,
                    "interval": "year",
                    "interval_count": 1,
                    "trial_period_days": null,
                    "usage_type": "licensed"
                },
                "tax_behavior": "exclusive",
                "tiers_mode": null,
                "transform_quantity": null,
                "type": "recurring",
                "unit_amount": 26880,
                "unit_amount_decimal": "26880"
            },
            {
                "id": "price_1KnjlbHa5WPIKK5IjVleb0hR",
                "object": "price",
                "active": true,
                "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                "created": 1649770103,
                "currency": "eur",
                "livemode": false,
                "lookup_key": null,
                "metadata": [],
                "nickname": null,
                "product": "prod_L7AxRKWZcChK9F",
                "recurring": {
                    "aggregate_usage": null,
                    "interval": "month",
                    "interval_count": 1,
                    "trial_period_days": null,
                    "usage_type": "licensed"
                },
                "tax_behavior": "exclusive",
                "tiers_mode": null,
                "transform_quantity": null,
                "type": "recurring",
                "unit_amount": 2490,
                "unit_amount_decimal": "2490"
            },
            {
                "id": "price_1KnjZsHa5WPIKK5IKzYgCusH",
                "object": "price",
                "active": true,
                "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                "created": 1649769376,
                "currency": "eur",
                "livemode": false,
                "lookup_key": null,
                "metadata": [],
                "nickname": null,
                "product": "prod_L6ugqTDvGjaptE",
                "recurring": {
                    "aggregate_usage": null,
                    "interval": "year",
                    "interval_count": 1,
                    "trial_period_days": null,
                    "usage_type": "licensed"
                },
                "tax_behavior": "exclusive",
                "tiers_mode": null,
                "transform_quantity": null,
                "type": "recurring",
                "unit_amount": 18900,
                "unit_amount_decimal": "18900"
            },
            {
                "id": "price_1KnjZAHa5WPIKK5I1MgPKICU",
                "object": "price",
                "active": true,
                "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                "created": 1649769332,
                "currency": "eur",
                "livemode": false,
                "lookup_key": null,
                "metadata": [],
                "nickname": null,
                "product": "prod_L6ugqTDvGjaptE",
                "recurring": {
                    "aggregate_usage": null,
                    "interval": "month",
                    "interval_count": 1,
                    "trial_period_days": null,
                    "usage_type": "licensed"
                },
                "tax_behavior": "exclusive",
                "tiers_mode": null,
                "transform_quantity": null,
                "type": "recurring",
                "unit_amount": 1749,
                "unit_amount_decimal": "1749"
            },
            {
                "id": "price_1KQwc6Ha5WPIKK5I27jjkNd8",
                "object": "price",
                "active": true,
                "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                "created": 1644337942,
                "currency": "eur",
                "livemode": false,
                "lookup_key": null,
                "metadata": [],
                "nickname": null,
                "product": "prod_L7Ay2QFGIFGWd7",
                "recurring": {
                    "aggregate_usage": null,
                    "interval": "year",
                    "interval_count": 1,
                    "trial_period_days": 30,
                    "usage_type": "licensed"
                },
                "tax_behavior": "inclusive",
                "tiers_mode": null,
                "transform_quantity": null,
                "type": "recurring",
                "unit_amount": 24900,
                "unit_amount_decimal": "24900"
            },
            {
                "id": "price_1KQwc6Ha5WPIKK5IM2tdjzCY",
                "object": "price",
                "active": true,
                "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                "created": 1644337942,
                "currency": "eur",
                "livemode": false,
                "lookup_key": null,
                "metadata": [],
                "nickname": null,
                "product": "prod_L7Ay2QFGIFGWd7",
                "recurring": {
                    "aggregate_usage": null,
                    "interval": "month",
                    "interval_count": 1,
                    "trial_period_days": 30,
                    "usage_type": "licensed"
                },
                "tax_behavior": "inclusive",
                "tiers_mode": null,
                "transform_quantity": null,
                "type": "recurring",
                "unit_amount": 2490,
                "unit_amount_decimal": "2490"
            },
            {
                "id": "price_1KQwb9Ha5WPIKK5IPXgHG5pc",
                "object": "price",
                "active": false,
                "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                "created": 1644337883,
                "currency": "eur",
                "livemode": false,
                "lookup_key": null,
                "metadata": [],
                "nickname": null,
                "product": "prod_L7AxRKWZcChK9F",
                "recurring": {
                    "aggregate_usage": null,
                    "interval": "year",
                    "interval_count": 1,
                    "trial_period_days": 30,
                    "usage_type": "licensed"
                },
                "tax_behavior": "inclusive",
                "tiers_mode": null,
                "transform_quantity": null,
                "type": "recurring",
                "unit_amount": 10900,
                "unit_amount_decimal": "10900"
            },
            {
                "id": "price_1KQwb9Ha5WPIKK5IJKkdL1LG",
                "object": "price",
                "active": false,
                "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                "created": 1644337883,
                "currency": "eur",
                "livemode": false,
                "lookup_key": null,
                "metadata": [],
                "nickname": null,
                "product": "prod_L7AxRKWZcChK9F",
                "recurring": {
                    "aggregate_usage": null,
                    "interval": "month",
                    "interval_count": 1,
                    "trial_period_days": 30,
                    "usage_type": "licensed"
                },
                "tax_behavior": "inclusive",
                "tiers_mode": null,
                "transform_quantity": null,
                "type": "recurring",
                "unit_amount": 1090,
                "unit_amount_decimal": "1090"
            }
        ],
        "has_more": true,
        "url": "/v1/prices"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are conflating [the Product and the Price](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide), which are two separate concepts/objects. A Product represents a description of the good or service you are selling. A Price determines how much and how often you will pay for a given Product. Each Price references a single Product, but you can have many Prices for the same Product.

While it does not appear that retrieve products & prices is support directly via Cashier, you can always do this with the Stripe API / `stripe-php` as below.

You can retrieve Prices for a given `product` using the API to list them with a filter ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/list#list_prices-product)):

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  'sk_test_123'
);
$stripe->prices->all(['product' => `prod_123`]);
```

And you can view the price set for a given Price object by retrieving it and looking at the `unit_amount`, `currency` and `recurring.interval` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/object)):

```
price = $stripe->prices->retrieve('price_456', []);
```

Comment: How can we retrieve the same in laravelcashier because when i am trying above solution i am getting class not found error.

Comment: You'll need to contact the Laravel Cashier developers to ask if/how this can be done. In the documentation I can access, I don't see support for directly access these Stripe resources.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66976301/how-we-can-preview-prorations-in-laravel-cashier-or-what-is-the-logic-of-calcula     Can u pls look into this question

Comment: Just do the same but instead of getting the ```$stripe``` object from the ```StripeClient```, just do: ```$stripe = Cashier::stripe();```

Answer (score 0):

You could show the current method both for making the request and for displaying it in `views`.